# mysql inner join group_concat mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

```
TABLE 1 : 
ID         CODE 
1,2,3,4,5  abc
2,3,4,5    xyz 

TABLE 2 :
ID   NAME
1    NM1
2    NM2
3    NM3
4    NM4
5    NM5
```

join is on ID .
I need to fetch NAME using join where CODE = 'abc'

Any help appreciated

Comment: is this kind of scenario possible???

Comment: not clear , please provide more details

Comment: i need to fetch NAMEs of IDs where CODE= 'abc'

Comment: Table1 ID is primary key or foreign key or just collection u using with numbers.

Comment: First see normalisation. Then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try function `find_in_set`:

```
select tbl2.name
from tbl1
join tbl2 on find_in_set(tbl2.id, tbl1.id) > 0
where tbl1.code = 'abc'
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2bc1/2) here.